# Static initialization order in class heirarchy

Tags: c++, initialization, static-initialization, initialization-order

I've recently become painfully aware of the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order). I am wondering though if the rule that "initialization order is undefined across translation units" still holds for static members in a parent class which are needed by static members in a child class.

For example, say we have (excluding, for brevity, all the # guards and includes)

```
// a.h
class A {
    static int count;
    static int register_subclass();
};

// a.cpp
int A::count = 0;
int A::register_subclass() {
    return count ++;
}
```

And then a sub-classes of `A`,

```
// b.h
class B : public A {
    static int id;
};

// b.cpp
int B::id = A::register_subclass();
```

There are two translation units here with static objects in one depending on static objects in the other on initialization... it seems like it may be an instance of the static initialization order fiasco.

My question is: *is it actually safe*?

That is, am I guaranteed that there is no chance that `B::id` will contain junk copied from `A::count` before the latter is initialized? From my own tests, `A` always seems to get initialized first, but I'm not sure how to introduce noise in the initialization order to increase the probability of failing if the behavior is undefined.

Comment: No. The order of a.cpp and b.cpp getting linked into the executable is *not* guaranteed. That *is* the "initialization order fiasco". (Your linker might use alphabetical order, or it might not).

Comment: @BoPersson I was afraid of that. Thanks. Make this an answer (and maybe provide a reference?) and I'll mark it accepted

Comment: @BoPersson: Answers go down there buddy  ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, it is not safe to rely on the static initialization order of a base class and derived class. There is no guarantee that the static initialization of `A` will happen before `B`. That is the definition of the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

You could use the *construct on first use* idiom:

```
// a.h
class A {
private:
    static int& count();
protected:
    static int register_subclass();
};

// a.cpp
int& A::count() {
    static int count = 0;
    return count;
}

int A::register_subclass() {
    return count()++;
}

// b.h
class B : public A {
public:
    static int id;
};

// b.cpp
int B::id = A::register_subclass();
```

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sO1rvs3oc0zHa2Ha)

**Update:** However,  saying that,  bogdan pointed out in comments

> according to [3.6.2] in the Standard, the order of initialization in this specific example is guaranteed. It has nothing to do with inheritance, but with the fact that the initialization of `A::count` is *constant initialization*, which is guaranteed to be done before *dynamic initialization*, which is what `B::id` uses.

But unless you have a complete grasp of such intracaccies I recommend you use the *construct on first use* idiom.

And it is ok in this case but be careful of functions like `A::register_subclass` in a multi-threaded context. If multiple threads call it simultaneously anything could happen.

Comment: Thanks - this is essentially the solution I ended up using. It's too bad that it's necessary to add that nasty static function cruft around my poor, simple little variable.

Comment: Actually, according to [3.6.2] in the Standard, the order of initialization in OP's specific example is guaranteed. It has nothing to do with inheritance, but with the fact that the initialization of `A::count` is *constant initialization*, which is guaranteed to be done before *dynamic initialization*, which is what `B::id` uses. `count ++`, however, can be a problem in the presence of threads - the initialization of `B::id` and some other `C::id` could potentially be run concurrently. cc @stett

Comment: The advice to use local `static`s is generally sound, but I think it may be worth clarifying the details above in the answer, in the interest of accuracy.

Comment: **−1** The initialization `int A::count = 0;` is completely redundant, because `A::count` has already been *zero-initialized*. I.e. (1) the definition `int A::count;` suffices, and (2) this ensures the safety of the example. This means that this answer's assertion "Generally, this is not safe" is wrong.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I've tried to make it more clear what I  meant by "generally".

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering though if the rule that "initialization order is undefined across translation units" still holds for static members in a parent class which are needed by static members in a child class.

Yes, it does.

The only way that static data members relate to inheritance hierarchies (or, really, their encapsulating classes at all) is in their fully qualified names; their definition and initialisation is completely unaware/uncaring of this.